# Passing database results to a another page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm working on an asp.net page where I am collecting user input, run the query in the database and display the result. I would like to display the result from the database to another different page. Below is my Example ..

---

```
string collect = "SELECT Customer ID FROM ReportDocumentNo WHERE Title = '" + title.Text + "' AND Author = '" + author.Text + "'";

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(collect, con);
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
Response.Redirect("customerNumber.aspx");

Label = temp.ToString(); //it doesn't work this way
```

---

In customerNumber.aspx page i would like to display the **temp** results in a Label. How can i make it work ..?

Comment: You need to learn about session variables.  Store the value you want to pass to the other page in a session variable, and in that other page you can read that value from the session variable.

Comment: You can pass the title and author through session variables, then run the query from that page, instead of passing the results.  

The way you are executing your sql leaves you open to SQL injection attack, you should consider sanitizing your inputs or running this SQL in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to store the temp variable in a Session variable, something like that :

```
Session["temp"] = temp.ToString();
```

and then :

```
Label.Text = (string) Session["temp"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your **temp** is not very long, and it would be safe to be public to anyone, you can also use `"QueryString"` to pass data through pages.We can truly pass data through pages using `"Session"`, but you should notice that session is usually used to save and pass a global data that belongs to a specific user and it is saved in your server, so when your website has a lot of users, an "abundant" session may burden your server.If you just need to pass **temp** between only these two pages and do not use it any more in other pages,`"QueryString"` may be a better choice.
Learn more about `"Session","QueryString","Application","cookie","Server.Transfer"`,these are several methods to pass data through pages in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
string collect = "SELECT Customer ID FROM ReportDocumentNo WHERE Title = '" + title.Text + "' AND Author = '" + author.Text + "'";

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(collect, con);
Response.Redirect("customerNumber.aspx?tmp="+Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar()));
```

and on the next page

```
Label.text = Request.QueryString["tmp"];
```